# For loop stopping after 1 loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ascii

I am trying to write some code to auto generate a bit of ASCII text based on input numbers. Basically the number input to the function would  get returned as the numbers "magnified" in ascii text. So an input of 0123456789 wold output:

```
-**----*--***--***---*---****--**--****--**---**--
*--*--**-----*----*-*--*-*----*-------*-*--*-*--*-
*--*---*---**---**--****-***--***----*---**---***-
*--*---*--*-------*----*----*-*--*--*---*--*----*-
-**---***-****-***-----*-***---**---*----**---**--
--------------------------------------------------
```

I coded each number line by line into an array and the code loops through the array for each number input and builds the combined end image. The generation part seems to be working properly, but for some reason my end variable is not properly available at the end, and the main loop only processes the first number of the input then stops. Any help is greatly appreciated! http://jsfiddle.net/dmcuj2z5/

```
function printNums(line){
    var nums = [['12','03','03','03','12'],['2','12','2','2','123'],['012','3','12','0','0123'],['012','3','12','3','012'],['1','03','0123','3','3'],['0123','0','012','3','012'],['12','0','012','03','12'],['0123','3','2','1','1'],['12','03','12','03','12'],['12','03','123','3','12']];

    var answer = ['','','','','',''];
    var allowed = '0123456789';
    for(var i=0;i<line.length;i++){
        var num = line[i];
        if(allowed.indexOf(num) !== -1){
            for(var l=0;l<6;l++){    
                var print = '';
                for(var c=0;c<5;c++){
                    if(nums[num][l].indexOf(c) !== -1){
                        print += '*';
                    }else{
                        print += '-';
                    }
                }
               answer[l] += print;
            }
        }
    }
    alert(answer);
}

printNums('123');
```

Comment: At least here `for(var l=0;l<6;l++){` should be 5, not 6

Comment: That was what was actually breaking it. I needed it to be 6 becasue the bottom line on all of the output should be the same, but I didn't have an empty entry for it in the arrays. Working now! thanks @Cheery ! http://jsfiddle.net/dmcuj2z5/2/

Comment: Note that `print` is a builtin function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your end variable is an array.
To output it just joint it with a new line:

```
function printNums(line){
    var nums = [['12','03','03','03','12'],['2','12','2','2','123'],['012','3','12','0','0123'],['012','3','12','3','012'],['1','03','0123','3','3'],['0123','0','012','3','012'],['12','0','012','03','12'],['0123','3','2','1','1'],['12','03','12','03','12'],['12','03','123','3','12']];

    var answer = ['','','','','',''];
    var allowed = '0123456789';
    for(var i=0;i<line.length;i++){
        var num = line[i];
        if(allowed.indexOf(num) !== -1){
            for(var l=0;l<5;l++){    
                var print = '';
                for(var c=0;c<5;c++){
                    if(nums[num][l].indexOf(c) !== -1){
                        print += '*';
                    }else{
                        print += '-';
                    }
                }
               answer[l] += print;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(answer.join("\n"));
}

printNums('123');

// --*--***--***--
// -**-----*----*-
// --*---**---**--
// --*--*-------*-
// -***-****-***--
```